# Wordpress thumbnail sizes

Tags: php, wordpress

In my functions.php i defined 2 dimensions i want to use on my site, small and custom-size and my file looks like this:

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
add_image_size('small', 120, '', true);
add_image_size('custom-size', 755, 220, true);
```

When i check my wp-content/uploads folder, except original image and 120px and 755px images i see several others dimensions (150px, 768px) and i was wondering why is that showing if i only have 2 dimensions (i am asking because i am on limited hosting and want to save on disk space because i host a lot of images).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are generally three reasons that these other sizes could be showing up:

- **You had different thumbnail dimensions / image sizes in the past.** Images are not re-created (or deleted) when you change image sizes, but you can use a plugin such as [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) to do this for you - just click the options it adds under the Tools menu, after you have changed your image sizes.
- **You have a plugin or theme installed that is creating additional image sizes.** To track down what is doing this, you can either search through the files for `add_image_size`, or you could deactive plugins/change themes and then regenerate your thumbnails to see what the result is.
- **Wordpress has a new hidden image size for responsive images.** This applies in the case of the **768px** image. See [this WP Core blog post](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/11/10/responsive-images-in-wordpress-4-4/) for details. If you have no need for responsive images you could change the size that applies to this image using the instructions in that blog post (running eg. `update_option('medium_large_size_w', '755')` or even manually updating the option in the database - it's in the `wp_options` table). Again - regenerate thumbnails after doing this.